# TinyMCE: how to switch between bbcode and WYSIWYG view?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce, bbcode

I'd like to use the [TinyMCE BBCode-Plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/bbcode.php) to let users style their texts.

The example (link above) shows how to

- turn the editor on/off
- edit the bbcode in an external window (click at the "HTML"-icon)

I'd like to show the source (=BBCode) in my editor without turning it on/off.

My current code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    plugins: [
        "bbcode link"
    ],
    toolbar: "bold italic underline | link unlink"
});
```

Does anyone have a workaround/plugin or a suggesstion to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance!